# I got an error while trying to do pod install "[!] FBReactNativeSpec has added 1 script phase."

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, npm

I got an error while trying to do pod install.

[!] FBReactNativeSpec has added 1 script phase. Please inspect before executing a build. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#script_phases` for more information."

My Configurations are:

1. macOS BigSur (11.4)
2. Xcode 12.5.1
3. Homebrew 3.2.1
4. react-native 0.64.2
5. node v14.17.3
6. npm 6.14.13

Please help me...

Comment: related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656616

Comment: also: https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/138

Comment: this worked for me (if you are using `nvm`): `nvm unalias default`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is related to the a dependency error on react-native@0.64.0. If you upgrade "***react-native-codegen***" to version 0.0.7 the error should be fixed. It solved my problem.

Add an exception to your package.json:

For yarn:

```
"resolutions": {
  "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7"
},
```

Run `yarn add --dev react-native-codegen` and rebuild IOS project.

All info here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31180

Answer (score 1):

Just run

```
npm install
```

in your project's directory and then

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

then build your app again

```
npx react-native run-ios
```